# Stored procedure only partially executes from PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure running in MS SQL 2008 R2 which runs fine in SQL Management Studio.  However, if I run it from PHP it seems to stop execution before finishing.  There is no error returned in SQL and no error returned in the PHP error log.  The procedure simply writes to an error log a number of times using a second stored procedure.  I have cut the code down to a simple loop to demonstrate reproducing the problem.  This is the main stored procedure.

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_failure_test]

AS
DECLARE
@counter int,
@message nvarchar(100)

SET @counter = 0;
WHILE @counter < 100
  BEGIN
    SET @message = 'COUNT: ' + CAST(@counter AS nvarchar);
    EXEC usp_log 0, 'TEST', @message;
    SET @counter += 1;
  END
EXEC usp_log 0, 'TEST', 'Finished';
```

This calls the procedure usp_log

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_log]
@engine_id int,
@type nvarchar(15),
@message text
AS
DECLARE
@last int,
@log_size int

INSERT INTO [dbo].[log] (engine_id, timestamp, type, message) VALUES (@engine_id, getdate(), @type, @message);
SET @log_size = CONVERT(int, (dbo.get_setting('log_size')))
SET @last = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM log ORDER BY id DESC)
DELETE FROM log WHERE id < (@last - @log_size)
return
```

If I execute usp_failure test from SSMS it writes all of the expected log entries and then stops successfully.  However, if I execute it from PHP (with the following code), it only reaches 52 and then stops without any clue as to why.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost\sqlexpress";
$connectionInfo = array("UID" => "xxx", "PWD" => "xxx", "Database"=>"xxx", "ReturnDatesAsStrings"=>true, "CharacterSet" =>"UTF-8");
$conn = @sqlsrv_connect($servername, $connectionInfo);
$query = "usp_failure_test";
$params = array();
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params);
?>
```

I have tried adding in extra lines of code and this makes it fail after even fewer iterations.  I have ensured that PHP has plenty of memory to work with and I've also checked the PHP and SQL logs to no avail.  We've also used SQL profiler which did not show up any issues either.

Comment: Could your PHP be timing out? How long does the code take to run?

Comment: Thanks for replying. As you can see this has now been answered successfully, but for the record it was taking about 0.25 sec to run, however, if I put extra lines of code in it would take less time to run and would stop after fewer iterations of the loop. After adding SET NOCOUNT ON to the start of the usp_log stored procedure it runs successfully for as many iterations as I need. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just so I know for future reference - how many iterations is you procedure running through? I've never come across something returning more data than the driver can handle!

Comment: @andrewsi - It likely isn't a problem with the amount of data per se, but rather the number of result sets.  Each insert/update query will create a "x row(s) affected" message which to PHP looks like a result set.

Comment: The original code was calling a procedure about 30 times.  Each of these would have written two or three entries into the log table using the SP above, as well as performing various SELECTs.  There were no INSERTS or UPDATES.  None of these procedures return any data other than a simple integer to indicate success or failure.  I had already manipulated the buffer size using the **sqlsrv_configure('ClientBufferMaxKBSize', 20000)** command but it made no difference.  It must be a different 'buffer' that is affected by the SET NOCOUNT ON setting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `SET NOCOUNT ON` in your stored procedures.  You are likely hitting a limit on the number of results that can be returned to PHP from the sql server PHP driver.

Comment: Brilliant and fast!!!  You were spot on - I've now tested it well into the 1000s of iterations.  Thank you.  Just one thing, is it necessary to append this to the start of ALL stored procedures or just the one called from PHP?  Thanks again.

Comment: @user - Typically I put that at the start of all my stored procedures, unless there is some reason why I would want to see the "x row(s) affected" messages (e.g. while debugging).

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me crazy!